# What effective laws and rules regulating perks of politicians and political parties exist in various democracies?

Tags: parties, spain, conflict-of-interest

In most, if not all countries, the rules regulating politicians and political parties are made by those very same politicians and political parties. In such cases, politicians tend to give themselves extra benefits over other citizens and organizations.

As these "perks" are beneficial to politicians as a group, I understand that there is little incentive for them to remove or even reduce them. I see a conflict of interest between the interests of the political class and society as a whole.

Have democracies attempted to regulate these? How?

---

**Examples of some questionable perks** in Spain:

- Lack of control over the assistance to Congress sessions despite it being compulsory [<sup>1</sup>](https://www.elespanol.com/espana/politica/20180214/crece-absentismo-congreso-diputados-pleno-adelantado-conciliar/284722756_0.html)
- Political parties are exempt from paying the added value tax for some operations[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2007-13022)

Comment: I agree that "very high salaries" is arguable. I will remove it from the examples.

Comment: In my examples, I included things that (I think) cannot be counted as rewards of the talent, but just unjustified benefits, like tax exemptions on political parties and lack of control over assistance to sessions (with evident abuse as result), so I understand the question is relevant at least in those cases.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Exchange isn't really a good platform for brainstorming questions like this. Our primary focus is to explain politics. Coming up with our own solutions to political problems isn't in our scope.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that a potential conflict of interest between the interests of the political class and society would be something relevant to political science and that this problem would have been studied and some control mechanisms would have been proposed. I didn't mean this as a "brainstorming" request. My bad.

Comment: I don't see the conflict of interest *per se* in the government ensuring officials are well looked-after. The official wants the perks, so they want to stay in office, so they want to win elections - that should *align* their interests with the political system at large, not push them into conflict. ("Winning elections" and "helping constituents" may not be particularly well aligned but that's a different, much broader discussion.)

Comment: I removed the other arguable examples, and just left the political party tax exemption and the lack of accountability in session assistance to avoid losing focus on the potential conflict itself.

Comment: Try to make in ontopic but focusing an present mechanism instead of what should/could exist. It should not be opinion-based anymore.

Comment: Would it be better to have underpaid officials who are more open to bribes because they need the money?

Comment: @JoeW I don't see the relation of tax exemptions on political parties and lack of accountability of politician work with reducing the likelihood of politicians accepting bribes.

Comment: While you removed the points about salary from your question I felt it was an important point to bring up as that is related to things such as being bribed.

Comment: But not related to the question anymore. I want to focus on the mechanisms to control the potential conflict of interests between the political class and society, so I removed precisely the points that drive people away from such a focus.

Comment: @JoeW the perennial question in politics. Do you want politicians who are openly corrupt so we can at least see the corruption, or ones who are quietly corrupt because we blocked them from anything that looks like corruption?

Comment: @user253751 Or do you want to remove reasons that they might become corrupt?

Comment: @JoeW strawman: what's being discussed is simply letting them be corrupt in what *might* be a *relatively* harmless way

Comment: @user253751 And I disagree there are many "perks" that are given to people, politicians included that are designed to prevent them from taking bribes and other forms of corruption.

Comment: @JoeW yes so that's an overt form of corruption designed to prevent less obvious forms

Comment: @user253751 As I said before I disagree with that. Not sure why you are trying to convince me otherwise

Answer (score 5):

In the end, it is generally accepted that the legislature (and not the executive) should have the *power of the purse*. Keeping their own expenses out of it is theoretically difficult.

- One option would be to require that salary increases, etc., only take effect *after* the next election. But that would mean a big jump every couple of years, rather than a measured annual increase.
- Another option would be to tie some of the compensation/perks of legislators to those of senior civil service employees. Legislators could still be tempted to boost *those* salaries, but it gets harder to do that out of sync with the general wage developments.
- I'm pretty sure that keeping foreign spyware *out* of a hundred different smartphone models costs much more than making sure that everybody has the standard model.

But in the end, those payments are trifling compared to a CEO with far less responsibility.

Comment: Reading some stories about the 3rd point, I doubt there's any systematic effort.

Comment: @Fizz, there are countries where an effort is made. (And sometimes leaders then take private phones to get around document laws ...)

Comment: The first bullet seems fallacious. Surely a legislature could mandate annual increases by some fixed percentage, or based on inflation, or some other economic metrics.

Comment: @JoelHarmon, that would mean either the current parliament *does* decide on their own next-year increase, if only by not adjusting the formula, or that the formula is fixed for the entire term. I haven't heard of suggestions like that, while I seem to recall suggestions that compensation increases should only come for the next parliament.